# Let $G$ be a semigroup such that:$ \forall a \in G, \exists b \in G \therefore axb=x, \forall x \in G $ show that $(G,\cdot)$ is an abelian group.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

Let G be a semigroup with properties: $ \forall a \in G, \exists b \in G \therefore axb=x, \forall x \in G $ show that $(G,\cdot)$ is an abelian group.

I have managed to show that there is a unit element, as below.
Let $ x\in G$,
$$ abx= a(abx)b=(aab)xb=axb=x$$
$$ xab=a(xab)b=ax(abb)=axb=x$$
so we have $ab=e$ (unit of the semigroup)

I'm looking for help on finding inverse elements and proving the commutative property. If you have any tips or feedback on my progress, I'd really appreciate it! I appreciate your assistance in advance. Thank you!

Comment: I was able to follow what you did in the first line. But in the second line, how do you get $abx=a(xab)b$?

Comment: @jjagmath It seems to be a typo. I think they meant $xab$ there.

Comment: @Koro Yes, that makes sense.

Comment: Your use of $\therefore$ is strange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use the symbol $b_a$ to show the dependence of $b_a$ on $a$.

So the given condition is: for every $a\in G$, there exists a $b_a$ in $G$ such that
$axb_a=x$ for every $x\in G$.

This implies that there exists a $b_x$ such that $xb_a b_x=b_a$ so

$axb_a=x\implies a(xb_ab_x)=xb_x\implies ab_a= xb_x \implies b_x$ is the right inverse of $x$.

Using associativity in the second equality below,

$b_xx= x(b_x x) b_x=(xb_x)^2=(ab_a)^2= ab_a \implies b_x$ is left inverse of $x$. It follows that $b_x$ is the inverse of $x$.

For Abelianness, note that for all $a,c\in G$,
$ac=c(ac)b_c=(ca)(cb_c)= ca$

Answer (score 3):

Writing $e$ for your unit, as $axb=x$ for all $x\in G$, taking $x=e$ gives us that $aeb=e$. But $aeb=(ae)b=ab$, and so $ab=e$. Thus, $b$ is the right inverse of $a$. As $a$ is arbitrary in $G$, every element has a right inverse.

Now, note that $b$ has a right inverse $c$. Then we may multiply both sides of $axb=x$ on the right by $c$ to get that $ax=xc$ for all $x\in G$. Taking $x=e$ gives us that $c=a$. Moreover, as $c=a$ and $ax=xc$ for all $x\in G$, we have that the element $a$ commutes with every element of $G$. As $a$ is arbitrary, $G$ is commutative. It follows that right inverses are inverses, and so $G$ is a group, and hence also an abelian group.

Comment: This shows that $b$ is a right inverse of $a$. Shouldn't it also be shown that $b$ is a left inverse of $a$?

Comment: @Koro Thanks for pointing this out. I've essentially noted that the commutativity argument does not require a left inverse; this then shows that the right inverse is also a left inverse.

Comment: Actually, groups can be defined using only right units and right inverses, see the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)#Equivalent_definition_with_relaxed_axioms). So the initial answer was actually perfectly fine.

Comment: @Claudius Thanks for pointing this out! I did wonder if that was true, but the restructuring was quicker and easier for me than trying to verify this.